# How did Harry Potter survive against the Dementors at the lake

Tags: harry-potter

Movie: Harry Potter And The Prisoner Of Azkaban

When the lake turns to ice Dementors appear. As we all see, Harry Potter used the spell "Expecto Patronum" It held off against 2 Dementors then it turned off.

Harry still survives though, how? Because future Harry saved him. But this is what I don't understand

How did Harry save himself? He would have needed to survive without the help of himself or else he would have died.

Think about it:

Harry dies = No time travel

Harry survives = No time travel because there wouldn't be a reason, UNLESS:

Harry survives because future him did not die. But this does not make sense. Harry was about to die so his future self would never have existed, so why did the Future Harry exist to save himself?

Can someone explain this nonsense to me please? Harry's future self shouldn't have existed in the first place, because Harry SHOULD have died

Comment: J.K. Rowling's timeline is made of *wibbly wobbly timey wimey... stuff*.